# 2D CAD library of bicycle parts

Tags: design, software, open-source

Does anybody know of a royalty-free, reasonably comprehensive source of 2D CAD files of bicycle parts? I use LibreCad so .dxf preferable, but most other formats possible. For personal use only.

Comment: Have you looked on grabcad? You might need to search for specific parts

Comment: Thanks, had seen grabcad but it looks like mostly 3D stuff. I'm more after 2D line diagram type stuff. Currently looking at options to trace to .dxf format through Inkscape.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about CAD, not cycling. Quick "smell test": a CAD expert who knows nothing about cycling will be familiar with CAD libraries and may be able to answer this question; a cyclist who knows nothing about CAD has no chance.

Comment: I'm really curious as to what you want 2D drawings of bike parts for. Are you looking for generic line drawings or accurate drawings of specific components?

Comment: Possibly https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/  might be more suitable ?   You want graphic files that happen to be bicycles.

Comment: Argenti - just generic line drawings for a rough and ready maintenance guide I wanted to put together. I've since found OEM drawings for most of what I want - much better.

Comment: Richard/Criggie - I'm quite happy for the question to be closed, but would be interested in the logic. Can you not describe this question as one which could be answered by a subset of cycling enthusiasts (who do a bit of CAD), just as much as one which could be answered by a subset of CAD enthusiasts (who are capable of evaluating bike CAD blocks). Not arguing any decision you make, just interested. And I would think any answer would be of more use to the cycling enthusiasts than the CADders.

Comment: @Dan_7378439012 I'm a regular cyclist who also does a bit of CAD, but (i) it's all 3D these days, and (ii) that's work, with exactly [one exception](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/7208/1344).  I'm still not clear whether you actually want to make stuff from these drawings or use the drawings themselves in some sort of art - the latter needs them to be plausible rather than precise

Comment: @Dan_7378439012 As I said, _all_ the knowledge that goes into an answer to your question is CAD knowledge.